# What the correct CSS styles to align these tables horizontally and make them responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm pretty new to CSS and I don't know what the correct CSS property is to move the table to the place where I want.

I tried using the `float: right` property but the table moves to the bottom right.

[image: Table]

Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hi @Kameron, sorry i cannot share the code because there's some confidential thing, basically its just a 3 separated table tag (no div, class).

Comment: of course! I just added an example media query of what you could do to make it responsive. See edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest all three `table`'s in a single parent `wrapper` and set it to `display: flex;`. You can then use `justify-content: space-around;` or `space-between` depending on your personal preference.

This get's all tables in a line. Then you can set a `width` on each table. I like to do a `calc` width so that it always fits my desired items. I then added `1em` of left and right `margin` so that the tables are spaced accordingly.

`table`'s are hardly responsive so I would suggest incorporating some `media-queries` for media screens. An example to make it responsive on a media screen would be to add a media query changing the flex to `flex-direction: column;`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

table {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  margin: 0 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep these 3 tables in a parent div and make it display:flex

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <div>
    Table 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Table 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Table 3
  </div>  
</div>
```

Refer this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   div .table-center {
          display:flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
    }

   div .table-right {
          display:flex;
          align-items: end;
          justify-content: end;
    }
```